# Xamarin Forms - get row count of azure table

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database

I use the following code to get the count of all rows in an azure table, which I then use later in the same function.  However, I find that when I try to use the variable tCount, in some instances where I have a large count the full count isn't returned by the time I use the vaiable.

For example, one table I know has over 1600 rows, yet when I look at the value of tCount it is only at 900-odd, if I place a 1 second delay after the line

```
tCount = ((IQueryResultEnumerable<T>)tableRowCount).TotalCount;
```

the correct count is returned, but I would rather do this without adding a delay.

I also tried to place the code in an async task and await it but got the same result.  Is there another way to do this?

```
var table = Client.GetSyncTable<T>();

            var tableRowCount = (await table.Take(0)
                   .IncludeTotalCount()
                   .ToEnumerableAsync());

            long tCount = 0;
            tCount = ((IQueryResultEnumerable<T>)tableRowCount).TotalCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you are doing, you can query database metadata and Dynamic Management Views to know the number of rows a table has. This method will be faster.

```
SELECT t.name ,s.row_count from sys.tables t
JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
ON t.object_id = s.object_id
AND t.type_desc = ‘USER_TABLE’
AND t.name like ‘%YourTableName%’
AND s.index_id = 1
```